# Get largest element in array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to find the biggest element of an array.

#### Code

```
static int FindBiggestElementInAnArray(int[] nums)
{
        int aaa = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < nums.Length; n++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < nums.Length; a++)
            {
                if (nums[n] >= nums[a])
                {
                    aaa++;
                    if (a == nums.Length - 1 && aaa == nums.Length)
                    {
                       return n;
                    }
                }
            }
            aaa = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 34, 5 };
        Console.Write(FindBiggestElementInAnArray(numbers));
    }
```

I get `9`, but I expect to get `34`.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why not simply `numbers.Max()`?

Comment: you can find the max by looping thru it only one time.

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise (or for homework), or is this for production code?  If for production code, writing your own sort without a good understanding of sorting algorithms is unlikely to produce an efficient result and you'd be better off depending on what the .NET developers give you.

Comment: I'm doing my teamwork

Comment: What is "teamwork"? Is this for school or a class or your own self-learning, or is it for production code (i.e. you are employed to write this code)?

Comment: Suggest hooking up a debugger, or adding some println() calls.

Comment: Self-Learning.Thanks for comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the array to get the maximum value and you only need to retain the largest value found thus far, so:

```
int max = Int32.MinValue;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
   if (array[i] > max) {
     max = array[i];
   }
}
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

You can also use `.Max()` and that does this in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple `Max()` function

```
static int Max(params int[] ints){
    var maxInt = int.MinValue;
    foreach(var number in ints){
        if (number > maxInt) {
            maxInt = number;    
        }
    }
    return maxInt;
}
```

Working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nfN4N)

EDIT: as a side note, you should be returning `nums[n]`, not `n` in your original post.  `34` is at index `9` in the array that you pass in, which is why you are getting the answer `9` instead of `nums[9]`, which is `34`.

Here is the [dotnetfiddle for this explanation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2njMx)